# i am getting the error code Error in tagAssert(body, type = "div", class = "content-wrapper") : what is casuing this?

Tags: plot

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Air Quality"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    checkboxInput("axisChoice","Flip axes"),
    dashboardBody(
      plotOutput("airquality")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$airquality<-renderPlot({
    if(input$axisChoice==TRUE){
      x < - airquality$Day
      y < - airquality$Temp
      plot(x, y,
           main= "scatterplot of air quality",
           xlab= "day",
           ylab= "temp"
      )
    }
    if(input$axisChoice==FALSE){
      x < - airquality$Temp
      y < - airquality$Day
      plot(x, y,
           main= "scatterplot of air quality",
           xlab= "day",
           ylab= "temp"
      )
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
```

i expected a scatter plot graph. I need help with this project. I keep getting an error message saying somthing is wrong and missing. I have spent an hour trying to figure out what is wrong with it and i cant seem to found the problem. I will apericate any help that someone can give me. I am hoping someone can help me with this problem. I need a scatter plot graph with days on the x axis and temps on the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs in your code, see comments I made inline.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Air Quality"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        checkboxInput("axisChoice","Flip axes")
    ),
    dashboardBody( # dashboardBody must be outside of dashboardSidebar
        plotOutput("airquality")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
    output$airquality<-renderPlot({
        if(input$axisChoice==TRUE){
            x <- airquality$Day # <- not < -
            y <- airquality$Temp
            plot(x, y,
                 main= "scatterplot of air quality",
                 xlab= "day",
                 ylab= "temp"
            )
        }
        if(input$axisChoice==FALSE){
            x <- airquality$Temp
            y <- airquality$Day
            plot(x, y,
                 main= "scatterplot of air quality",
                 xlab= "day",
                 ylab= "temp"
            )
        }
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
```